# binding_of_caller gem error in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I am working on Rails 3.2.1 application and this is  my Gemfile:

```
group :development do
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
end
```

While running **bundle install**, I got the following error:

> An error occurred while installing binding_of_caller
>   (0.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install
>   binding_of_caller -v '0.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.

With some R & D, I run **bundle update binding_of_caller**, this time it's different error:

> An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Comment: where is the errors?

Comment: those gems have ext part so, provide also error part of `mkmf.log` for both